# How to only log queries without executing for Postgres Server?

Tags: postgresql

Is there any way I can make postgres server only log incoming statements without  executing them ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, any semi-sane program would go crazy after a couple of queries that return no sensible data and have no impact on future queries.

What is the problem you're trying to solve this way?

Comment: I have some modification in postgres code, I just want to collect all statements from application and later run them as testcase. Currently some statement crash my server and I would like to avoid that.

Comment: I think you'll have to log them while executing and extract from the log.